# How to grab a word from a file using sed or grep

Tags: grep, sed

I am trying to pull a piece of text from a file to use as input for the next command.  The word always starts with "JID_" and then some random numbers/characters after that.

For example :

```
        SelectorSet
            Selector: InstanceID = JID_001264193601, __cimnamespace = root/dcim
```

I want to assign a variable $JID to that string of characters.  How do I pull it from the line ?  sed or grep preferrably, but any method is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
(03:45 PM):(Jacob@houston)~$ egrep -o "JID_[0-9]+" bah | cut -d _ -f2
```

001264193601

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just hacked at it for a few minutes and came up with this :

```
grep JID job.txt | sed -e "s/.*InstanceID = //" -e "s/,.*//"
```

With output of this :

```
JID_001264194552
```

I think that will work.

Comment: I think he just wants to output the characters after JID_

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
var=$(sed -n 's/.*InstanceID = JID_\([0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p')
echo $var
```

will output this:

```
001264193601
```

for the given input.

If you want to keep the "JID_":

```
var=$(sed -n 's/.*InstanceID = \(JID_[0-9]\+\),.*/\1/p')
```

Comment: I want to know the \1/p at the last line of both commands you mentioned what it does?

Comment: @RegisteredUser: The `\1` brings forward the string that was captured by the first (in this case only) `\(\)` before the middle slash (in this case it's a sequence of one or more digits). The `p` after the final slash cause the result to be printed since the `-n` option turns off automatic printing. Using these together prevents any output of lines that do not match the regular expression between the first and middle slashes.